# VBA Excel Column Sorting Run Time Error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I want to sort column A without using select but I keep Getting error massage,

> Unable to get the sort property of the range class

```
'Sort Managers
With QueWS.Columns("A:A")
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A2:A" & LastRow), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Que").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1", Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Que")
    .Sort.SortFields.Clear
    .Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Que").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End With
```